# Is there any possibilities to change or update Data of firebase Database from pop window shows onLongClickListener

Tags: android, firebase

I want to show a list of option Delete & Update after long press on listview and after clicking update it show a new pop window to update a specific data that will update data in firebase and after closing, it will update the list.

Comment: Yup, that sounds possible. But it's impossible to show how with the current level of detail, and Stack Overflow is also not a code-writing service. If you're having issues implementing it, please post back with the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270933/should-i-answer-is-it-possible-type-of-questions

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, implement dialog box in OnItemLongClickListener() , then you will get the users answer , implement your code according to the users options ,try and write some code, share what you are trying.